# Why AWS limits the number of elastic IPs to 8?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Recently I stumbled upon an interesting limit on Amazon Web Services EC2. I noticed that the default available elastic IPs are limited to 8. Why is this? A colleague of mine told me that this is by design so that AWS users would build their systems secure with only limited number of entry points. Can someone elaborate the reasoning behind this limitation?

Comment: Amazon has a real and finite amount of addresses that they can allocate -- it only makes sense that they would have some default limit.

Comment: most services have limits on them (you just didn't hit em yet). the one on elastic ips makes sense in the context of having a limited number of public ips.

Comment: Just want to point out that this is covered in the Elastic IP documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#using-instance-addressing-limit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike oil, IP4 addresses are limited and theoretically you can have a max of 4.2 billion IP4 addresses. That is a lot of addresses but AWS does not have many at its disposal. AWS was not a big player (not even in existence) when /8 blocks were given away by ARIN. So AWS started acquiring IP address and has few million addresses and continues to acquire more IPs. There are brokers like [Addrex](https://addrex.net/) to facilitate this.

So IP address is a scarce resource for AWS and it wants to use the resource judiciously. To be fair to all customers, it is imposing a limit on a number of IPs allocated to an account which can be increased upon request. To curb the misuse of requesting an IP and leaving it unused, AWS charges 5 cents/hr/IP for unattached elastic IPs.

Just like treasure hunters looking for gold in sunken ships, there are companies specializing in unearthing unused IP addresses from defunct companies and help them sell those unused IP addresses in marketplace like Addrex. Recently the defunct Borders book store sold its IP block for millions of dollars. If you have a /20 block, you can expect $10/address, /16 will fetch you more, /8 - you are talking about few hundred million dollars.

Interesting read: [U.S. Will Run Out of Internet Addresses](http://www.wsj.com/articles/coming-this-summer-u-s-will-run-out-of-internet-addresses-1431479401)

Answer (score 1):

It's all to do with IPv4 addresses being a limited resource.

Note that in AWS an Elastic IP is a public IP, but a public IP is not necessarily an Elastic IP.

When you launch an instance in EC2-Classic, it's automatically assigned a public IP. When you launch in VPC, you decide if it's assigned a public IP. Those public IPs are not Elastic IPs.